# loadrunner cut of web_reg_save_param_ex() without right boundry

Tags: correlation, loadrunner

Using FireBug to sniff for correlation candidates I typically have this response header:

```
Response Headersview source

Cache-Control   no-cache, no-store

Content-Length  0

Date    Fri, 08 Mar 2013 13:22:37 GMT

Expires Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT

Location http://c24jbs300014.test.local:8080/something/someotherthing/171330/considertakingadump?24

Pragma  no-cache

Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

In the above response header I have correlated the value 24 like this:

```
        web_reg_save_param_ex(

            "ParamName=correlationID",

            "LB=considertakingadump?",

            "RB=",

            SEARCH_FILTERS,

            "Scope=Headers",

            LAST);
```

And it gets picked up, and it works to correlate in the script like this:

```
    web_submit_data("submitit", 

            "Action=http://c29jbsl00015.test.local:8080/something/treatment/{someothercorrelatedvalue}/someotherstuff?{correlationID}-1.IBehaviorListener.0-tabbedPanel-content-panels-0-panel-tableBody-somepoint-0-somepoint-somepoint-somepoint", 

            "Method=POST", 

            "RecContentType=text/xml", 

            "Referer=http://c29jbsl00015.test.local:8080/something/treatment/{someothercorrelatedvalue}/someotherstuff?9", 

            "Snapshot=t63.inf", 

            "Mode=HTTP", 

            ITEMDATA, 

            "Name=valgtBeslutning", "Value=0", ENDITEM, 

            LAST);
```

However when looking at the log (extended for parameter substituion) I see that a lot of the response is part of the constructed URL like this:

```
Action.c(618): Redirecting "http://c29jbsl00015.test.local:8080/something/treatment/171334/considerit?24&10Content-Length:+0HTTP/1.1+200+OKServer:+Apache-Coyote/1.1Date:+Fri,+08+Mar+2013+13:27:35+GMTExpires:+Thu,+01+Jan+1970+00:00:00+GMTPragma:+no-cacheCache-Control:+no-cache,+no-storeContent-Type:+text/html%3Bcharset=UTF-8Transfer-Encoding:+chunked-1.ILinkListener-nesteContent-Length:+0HTTP/1.1+200+OKServer:+Apache-Coyote/1.1Date:+Fri,+08+Mar+2013+13:27:35+GMTExpires:+Thu,+01+Jan+1970+00:00:00+GMTPragma:+no-cacheCache-Control:+no-cache,+no-storeContent-Type:+text/html%3BcharsetContent-Length: 0HTTP/1.1 200 OKServer: Apache-Coyote/1.1Date: Fri, 08 Mar 2013 13:27:35 GMTExpires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMTPragma: no-cacheCache-Control: no-cache, no-storeContent-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8Transfer-Encoding: chunked-1.IBehaviorListener.0-tabbedPanel-content-panels-0-panel-tableBody-kontrollpunkter-0-kontrollpunkt-beslutningForm-valgtBeslutning" (redirection depth is 0)   [MsgId: MMSG-26694]
```

Not having a right boundry in my server response is the reason for this.

Is there a way to say i.e. "set right boundry to newline (\n)" or something similar to cut-off this long and useless info in my web_reg_save_param()? As in after the number 24 in my server response?

Comment: In my web_submit_data() above it is recorded a "Referer" that is a link. What is a referer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why dont you use SaveLen

web_reg_save_param_ex(

```
        "ParamName=correlationID",

        "LB=considertakingadump?",

        "RB=",

                      "savelen=2",

        SEARCH_FILTERS,

        "Scope=Headers",

        LAST);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use non visible control characters such as \r,\n,\t, ....  as left or right boundary conditions.

IF you have a variable content line that always begins with "location," ends with "\n" of which you need the last two characters, then you can always capture the entire line and then use standard string processing capabilities of C to pull the last two characters of the line, such as playing the game of "move the pointer" to the last two characters of the string

```
&lr_eval_string("{My_captured_long_line}")[strlen(lr_eval_string("{My_captured_long_line}")) -2]
```